# Pygame error: No module named 'pygame.base'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, installation

I'm using Python 3.5, and the version of pygame designed for it. I have now installed pygame, by converting to zip and moving the files like in this video [*here*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdGoAnFP-mU). However when I run the command `import pygame`, the error `ImportError: No module named 'pygame.base'` appears.

Using this method of installation has worked fine in the past, but ever since getting a new PC, isn't working. What is wrong, and how do I fix the problem?

**Edit:**

I tried using the answer found on [Game Dev SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108998/pygame-for-python-3-5), however this gave me the error: `not a supported wheel on this platform`

The version of pygame I'm trying to install is: `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl`. Which can be found [*here*](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Comment: There is no version of pygame for python 3.5

Comment: This seems to be answered on [GameDev SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/108998/pygame-for-python-3-5).

Comment: @Fredrik There is here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra I tried this and I got the error, `not a supported wheel on this platform`

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox That is not an official release. The official releases can be found on the pygame bitbucket site https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads As today they support up to python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

This is for windows 10 64 bit.  Run the 64 bit python as administrator it should import pygame without problem. It worked for me 
Make sure pygame folder is copied under C:\Program Files\Python35\Lib\site-packages\ before you start python

Answer (score 0):

try usin pip3 install pygames to install pygames

```
pip3 install pygame
```